# SQL Server : what happens in delete with index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have a heap table of 36 million rows, I am trying to delete selected 6 million rows. When I delete in 100 of batches reads is 16++++++ and write is 113 so I add NON-clus index on Identity column to make read faster, now read is 34899 and write is 3508 with adding one NON-clus Idx it increase the write IO shoot up.

So what to know why this much difference what SQL Server does in the background as in plan I see table delete is 8% and no more details.

Also when I delete the my data pages and used pages are getting increased, incredibly.. I query sys.allocation units to check

When I delete 2500 rows my log file increase to 42 MB and fragmentation grows from 0.02 to 2.96

Just to add more before doing this I drop 2 Nvarchar column, and clean the table and rebuild it

Comment: I somewhat understand your question as an INFORMATION rather than QUESTION.

Comment: If you have a heap and delete without TABLOCK hint, SQL Server does not deallocate the space. That makes it of course more simple, but at some point you're going to need to do something to the wasted space...

Answer (score 0):

Change the nonclustered index to a clustered index. When you delete rows from a table SQL Server has to remove pages from the heap and pages from the indexes. If you have a clustered index then SQL Server only has to remove rows from this index.

Comment: Thanks :)  I did change.. now the read is 252 , which is considered as best in this situation. But when i add one more Non-cluster index with another 4 columns (nvarchar , int , money) read again shoots to 1300. is this the behavior or i need to consider the fillfactor for this ?

Comment: Any delete has to remove data from the table and the indexes.